# Axon framework: How to retrieve id of a state-stored aggregate id in a unit test

Tags: java, axon

I am new to Axon framework and am trying to implement an application using CQRS with state-stored aggregates.  The aggregate is created via a command handling constructor that assigns a random UUID as the aggregate identifier.

To test commands on the aggregate, I create the aggregate via a `givenCommands(new CreatePlanCommand(...)` call.  I then want to issue the command under test, `UpdatePlanNameCommand` in this case, but that command needs the aggregate id that was assigned by the `CreatePlanCommand` executed in the test setup.  Is there a way to retrieve this?

Example test code shown below (see question in comment on `when()` call):

```
@Test
public void plan_updatePlan_updatesPlanName() {
    testFixture
            .givenCommands(new CreatePlanCommand(123L, "My Test Plan", funds))
            .when(new UpdatePlanNameCommand(/* How to get aggregate id returned by CreatePlanCommand here? */, "New Name"))
            .expectSuccessfulHandlerExecution()
            .expectState(state -> {
                assertThat(state.getCompanyId(), equalTo(123L));
                assertThat(state.getName(), equalTo("New Name"));
                assertThat(state.getAvailableFunds(), equalTo(funds));
            });
}
```

The command handler that creates the plan is as follows:

```
@CommandHandler
public Plan(CreatePlanCommand command, PlanFundValidator planFundValidator) {
    // Use injected domain service to verify that all funds in this plan's lineup actually exist
    planFundValidator.validateFundsExist(command.getAvailableFunds());

    this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
    this.companyId = command.getCompanyId();
    this.name = command.getName();
    this.availableFunds = new HashSet<>(command.getAvailableFunds());
    apply(planCreatedEvent());
}
```

---

Update: I was able to get the test working by using `.givenState(...)` to create the aggregate as follows:

```
@Test
public void plan_updatePlan_updatesPlanName() {
    AtomicReference<UUID> planId = new AtomicReference<>();
    testFixture
            .givenState(() -> {
                Plan plan = new Plan(new CreatePlanCommand(123L, "My Test Plan", funds), mockPlanFundValidator);
                planId.set(plan.getId());
                return plan;
            })
            .when(new UpdatePlanNameCommand(planId.get(), "New Name"))
            .expectSuccessfulHandlerExecution()
            .expectState(state -> {
                assertThat(state.getCompanyId(), equalTo(123L));
                assertThat(state.getName(), equalTo("New Name"));
                assertThat(state.getAvailableFunds(), equalTo(funds));
            });
}
```

but this seems overly verbose and a step backwards in terms of test readability and maintenance, so I am still curious if there is a way to accomplish this with `.givenCommands(...)`.  Thank you.

Comment: Isn't the `123L` your `aggregateId`? From the way you built your command, I would assume so.

Comment: No, that is the natural id of the aggregate (the company id the plan is for).  The actual aggregate id is a UUID.  Unfortunately, I don't think I can change this design due to an established company convention requiring separate internal and external identifiers.

Comment: Yes but how do you generate that ID? Inside the CommandHandler? If you can add the code snippet of the command handler that actually creates your aggregate, that would be nice.

Comment: I added the code for the command handling constructor to the original question. Thank you.

Comment: Related question: is there a way to clear any events that were raised in the given part of a test? For example, if I have a unit test for command "C" that executes commands "A" and "B" as part of its "given" to set up the test, I would like to be able to assert that command "C" (the command under test) raised the expected events and not see any events raised by commands "A" and "B" since those are not the subject of this test and have their own tests that verify they raise the expected events.  Thank you.

Comment: All right, let me provide an answer to that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, let me try to give you some info on that.

In my opinion, the easiest way to achieve it is to move the UUID generation to another Component. In that way, you can clearly mock it on tests.

eg:

```java
@CommandHandler
public Plan(CreatePlanCommand command, PlanFundValidator planFundValidator, UUIDGenerator generator) {
    // Use injected domain service to verify that all funds in this plan's lineup actually exist
    planFundValidator.validateFundsExist(command.getAvailableFunds());

    this.id = generator.generate(); // changed this line
    this.companyId = command.getCompanyId();
    this.name = command.getName();
    this.availableFunds = new HashSet<>(command.getAvailableFunds());
    apply(planCreatedEvent());
}
```

Doing that, same way you mocked the `PlanFundValidator`, you also mock the `UUIDGenerator` making sure you have the needed id.

For the other question:

> Related question: is there a way to clear any events that were raised in the given part of a test? For example, if I have a unit test for command "C" that executes commands "A" and "B" as part of its "given" to set up the test, I would like to be able to assert that command "C" (the command under test) raised the expected events and not see any events raised by commands "A" and "B" since those are not the subject of this test and have their own tests that verify they raise the expected events.

The events are not kept from test to test but if those are raised by your own test, than you have to deal with them. By the `givenState` you find out earlier can also help with this. You just have to setup the state you need and fire the command/event you are testing.

Comment: Thank you - I like the idea to inject an ID generator.

Comment: Is exposing events that are generated in the "given" part of the test expected / desired behavior?  It seems to clutter the tests and makes it difficult (impossible?) to determine whether events were raised by the command under test or the "given" test setup.  In my opinion, the "then" portion of the test should only be asserting the behavior of the command under test (the "when" portion), or at least have that option.  Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "exposing events generated in the given"? `given` is just a simple way to setup the current state of your Aggregate before you test it... just a shortcut I would say. You can also use the counterpart of it, called `givenCommands` or the `givenNoPriorActivity` if you want to really start it empty.

Comment: It would be helpful if there was a way to assert the events that were raised in the `when` portion of the test ignoring events raised by `givenCommands` so that a test can assert that a given sequence of events were raised by the command under test without having to consider side effects of the test setup.  In my opinion, this would make the tests more self contained.  Thank you.